# How to fuse orientation from two IMUs in Robot Localization?

Tags: imu, robot-localization, ros-noetic

I'm working with a setup that includes a 9-axis IMU0 providing absolute orientation with respect to north and a 6-axis IMU1. Upon power-on, the 9-axis IMU0 shows a value relative to north, while the 6-axis IMU1 starts at zero.

IMU0 is a Cube orange flight controller. IMU1 is an integrated Ouster OS1 128.

Can I effectively fuse data from both IMUs using the Robot Localization package in ros-noetic? If so, what steps should I take to ensure  meaningful fusion of orientation data?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is entirely possible. Check out the documentation:

http://docs.ros.org/en/noetic/api/robot_localization/html/preparing_sensor_data.html#imu